# No liblwgeom when using postgresql84 and postgis on Snow Leopard with MacPorts

Tags: postgresql, osx-snow-leopard, macports, postgis

I'm trying to get my dev environment back up and running after upgrading to Snow Leopard.  In particular, I need postgresql and postgis working, but I'm running into the following problem.

After installing both with the following:

```
sudo port install postgresql84 postgresql84-server postgis
```

I get errors like the following when I try to load my sql database, which has references to liblwgeom.so

```
ERROR:  function public.box3d_in(cstring) does not exist
ERROR:  incompatible library "/usr/local/pgsql/lib/liblwgeom.so": version mismatch
DETAIL:  Server is version 8.4, library is version 8.3.
```

That file does exist on my computer, but must be sitting around from an old install of postgresql 8.3.  The problem is I can't figure out where liblwgeom.so is supposed to come from.  It's not included in postgis 1.4, and a Google search is leaving me scratching my head.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

liblwgeom.so comes with PostGIS vesion 1.3. It has been renamed in 1.4. It looks like your dump is of a database with PostGIS 1.3 and you're trying to reload in PostGIS 1.4. This is not supported.

See the PostGIS manual on [upgrading](http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-1.4/ch02.html#upgrading) for details on what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Update your ports:

```
sudo port selfupdate
```

Then install postgis 1.4, which will work for postgresql 8.4

```
sudo port install postgis
```