# Errors in Migration of an old PostgreSQL Database with Postgis Objects

Tags: postgresql, migration, postgis

We have a very old Linux system running PostgreSQL 8.3. The system contains a database with Postgis functions, but, from pgAdmin III interface, no 'Extensions' seem enabled. That server machine is going to go obsolete and we want to move to another Postgres server.

Currently we have a Windows server Postgres 9.3. I have been able to create a custom .backup file and am able to import most of the tables and data using the approach per: http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiWinUpgrade but my error.txt file says:

```
function makepoint(double precision, double precision) does not exist
```

and I think this function is part of the `liblwgeom.dll` and I can't find that DLL file anywhere! I have gone through most of the zip downloads from: http://download.osgeo.org/postgis/windows/ but no luck.

The original database does have a 'makepoint' function as below but it doesn't work on the target Windows system because of a lack of the DLL.

What are my options?

Maybe a different approach is needed. Please note, per the http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-svn/postgis_installation.html#hard_upgrade I had also tried the 'Hard Upgrade' using the .backup file in a Linux environment but got some error like 'invalid header', presumably due to the pg restore tool being too new; in Linux, my progress was way less than in the Windows one.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION makepoint(double precision, double precision)
RETURNS geometry AS '$libdir/liblwgeom', 'LWGEOM_makepoint'
LANGUAGE c IMMUTABLE STRICT COST 1; ALTER FUNCTION makepoint(double   precision, double precision)  OWNER TO postgres;
```

***Edit*** This is a Windows system and so the proposed Mac OS suggestion is not valid. Thanks though.

Comment: It's `ST_MakePoint` now. You have to upgrade postgis.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No liblwgeom when using postgresql84 and postgis on Snow Leopard with MacPorts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413600/no-liblwgeom-when-using-postgresql84-and-postgis-on-snow-leopard-with-macports)

Comment: ST_MakePoint sounds promising but how do I create the function makepoint() in my workflow while pointing to that? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Back in PostGIS 1.2.3, functions were renamed with a `ST_` prefix, so the modern name of `makepoint(float8, float8)` is `st_makepoint(float8, float8)`.

You can either rename the functions where they are used to the modern naming scheme, although this can be difficult to do if you have various functions, trigger functions, etc.

You can also run the `legacy.sql` enabler script that came with your installation of PostGIS, which will re-enable old functions, such as `makepoint(float8, float8)` and many others.

Comment: Mike, thanks. So, considering I have almost all the data objects migrated inside the Windows environment how can I make a new function called 'makepoint()' by pointing to the Postgis assemblies/DLL? I want to use the .backup file.

Comment: Look for the `share\contrib\postgis-x.y\legacy.sql` file on the Windows server.

Comment: Yes, legacy.sql does exist in my Windows postgis environment. WOuldn that automatically run as I ran the .bat file?

Comment: Normally you would use `psql -f legacy.sql mydbname`, but you can also open it in pgAdmin III. Run this first, then you can use the .backup file

Comment: pgAdmin III  was used to create a .backup file from the old database. Then created a new database, enabled postgis on that, then ran the .bat command. So where would legacy.sql fit?

Comment: Run `legacy.sql` on the database after `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`, but before running `upgrade.bat`. It will have the database ready with the correct [old] functions in-place before restoring.